# Transmit data on current xaml-page with Xamarin-Button

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

i have a Crousell-Page in a Xamarin.Forms application. You are able to swipe between several pictures on this page. I now want to define a button, that executes an action in the code-behind file. The point is, that i want to transmit the information **which picture is shown in the moment the button is clicked**.

I would be very grateful for helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The point is, that i want to transmit the information which picture is shown in the moment the button is clicked.

As Jason said that CarouselPage is just a collection of ContentPages,you can get current contentpage by ContentPage page = carousepages.CurrentPage; I do one sample that you can get a look:

```
<CarouselPage
x:Class="CarouselPageNavigation.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Name="carousepages">
<ContentPage x:Name="redcontentpage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            FontSize="Medium"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Red" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="get current page" />
        <BoxView
            x:Name="redbox"
            HeightRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="200"
            Color="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage x:Name="greencontentpage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            FontSize="Medium"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Green" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn2"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="get current page" />
        <BoxView
            x:Name="greenbox"
            HeightRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="200"
            Color="Green" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage x:Name="nluecontentpage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            FontSize="Medium"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Blue" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn3"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="get current page" />
        <BoxView
            x:Name="bluebox"
            HeightRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="200"
            Color="Blue" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

You can get the current Page BoxView by the following code:

```
 private  void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentPage page = carousepages.CurrentPage;
        StackLayout stack = (StackLayout)page.Content;
        BoxView box = (BoxView)stack.Children[2];                 


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailled description! Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a `CarouselView` this is easy.  The `CurrentItem` property will return the currently selected item

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var item = (MyModel)MyCarouselView.CurrentItem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately i need to use CarouselPage. So i am searchin for an option to **pass the information with the buttonClickedEvent**.

Comment: since a CarouselPage is just a collection of ContentPages, each page will have to have it's own Button and code-behind, so you can just hardcode the value